# how to save changes to config directory

Tags: vim, putty

I'm trying to save changes to a /var/www/ config directory for my virtual server.  I hit Ctrl X and am now in "X mode" but my Putty is unresponsive.  What can I do to save these changes and exit?

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect `<C-x>` to do? Vim is not nano.

First let's solve your immediate issue:

1. Hit `<Esc>` to get out of "^X mode".
2. Hit `<Esc>` to get out of insert mode.
3. Assuming you have the right privileges, type `:wq` to write the file and quit.

Second, Vim is not at all like nano, it's a modal editor. The normal mode is the mode you are in when you start Vim, it's the mode where you issue editing commands like "copy", "cut", paste", "search" and the mode from where you issue administrative commands like "open file foo.txt", "write this file" or "quit without writing".

Saving is done by typing `:w` in normal mode. Quitting is `:q`.

You can read about "^X mode" in `:help ins-completion`.